# Do I need network's SIM in in order to receive OTA update

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, sim-card, ota-update

I have a UK HTC Magic which is from Vodafone - I am in France for the time being and don't have the Vodafone SIM in. The phone is on the internet via wifi a lot.

Do I need to have Vodafone's sim in the phone in order to receive the Froyo OTA update that was announced today?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't. The updates are received from the Servers of the Provider/Manufacturer. This adress is saved in the ROM. So you just need an internet connection via 3g or wifi.